# How best cache bigquery table for fast lookup of individual row?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a raw data table in bigquery that has hundreds of millions of rows. I run a scheduled query every 24 hours to produce some aggregations that results a table in the ballmark of 33 million rows (6gb) but may be expected to grow slowly to approximately double its current size.

I need a way to get 1 row at a time quick access lookup by id to that aggregate table in a separate event driven pipeline. i.e. A process is notified that person A just took an action, what do we know about this person's history from the aggregation table?

Clearly bigquery is the right tool to produce the aggregate table, but not the right tool for the quick lookups. So I need to offset it to a secondary datastore like firestore.  But what is the best process to do so?

I can envision a couple strategies:

1) Schedule a dump of agg table to GCS. Kick off a dataflow job to stream contents of gcs dump to pubsub. Create a serverless function to listen to pubsub topic and insert rows into firestore.

2) A long running script on compute engine which just streams the table directly from BQ and runs inserts. (Seems slower than strategy 1)

3) Schedule a dump of agg table to GCS. Format it in such a way that can be directly imported to firestore via `gcloud beta firestore import gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[EXPORT_PREFIX]/`

4) Maybe some kind of dataflow job that performs lookups directly against the bigquery table? Not played with this approach before. No idea how costly / performant.

5) some other option I've not considered?

The ideal solution would allow me quick access in milliseconds to an agg row which would allow me to append data to the real time event.

Is there a clear best winner here in the strategy I should persue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that you could also CLUSTER your table by id - making your lookup queries way faster and less data consuming. They will still take more than a second to run though.

- https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b

You could also set up exports from BigQuery to CloudSQL, for subsecond results:

- https://medium.com/@gabidavila/how-to-serve-bigquery-results-from-mysql-with-cloud-sql-b7ddacc99299

And remember, now BigQuery can read straight out of CloudSQL if you'd like it to be your source of truth for "hot-data":

- https://medium.com/google-cloud/loading-mysql-backup-files-into-bigquery-straight-from-cloud-sql-d40a98281229

Comment: This is solid. Thank you. I was a little surprised to do the math and learn that rewriting my entire agg table to firestore would cost somwhere around $72 per sync.  ($0.18 per 100,000 documents X ~40M docs). Would it be a possible alternative to write each of my agg rows as a document in cloud storage? Is that a really bad use of storage? It's not like I need query ability. More just key/value storage.

Comment: After trying several approaches I ended up coming back to exactly this solution. Thanks!  I first run a query between my BQ source-of-truth table against my cloud postgres to determine which rows are different. I then export to GCS and then from GCS to a cloud function (via pubsub via dataflow) to do the actual CRUD in cloud SQL. I wrapped all the above into a bash script to run via a cron job. It's fast, cheap, and keeps my cloud SQL in sync with bigquery.  Thanks Felipe!

Comment: glad to hear it was useful!